# @Id Not Mapped For Specific Entity In A Spring-Boot Controller

Tags: spring-boot, jackson, spring-web

I have two entities `Employee` and `Department` and each have a Spring Web `@RestController` annotated class with update methods i.e. `Http PUT`.

For some strange reason (and likely a blindingly obvious solution) whenever the `PUT` is called for the `Employee` class, the ID in the JSON payload is NOT mapped to the `id` class of the `Employee` entity but it works perfectly for the `Department` entity.

`Employee` class:

```
Entity
@Table(name = "EMPLOYEE")
public class Employee implements Serializable, Identity<Long>, Deleted
{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "NAME")
    private String name;

    @ManyToOne
    @Where(clause = "is_deleted = false")
    private Department department;

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinTable(name = "EMP_QUAL", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "EMPLOYEE_ID"), inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "QUALIFICATION_ID"))
    @WhereJoinTable(clause = "IS_DELETED = false")
    @SQLDelete(sql = "UPDATE `EMP_QUAL` SET IS_DELETED = true where EMPLOYEE_ID = ? and QUALIFICATION_ID = ? and IS_DELETED = False")
    private Set<Qualification> qualifications;

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinTable(name = "EMP_PROJ", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "emp_id"), inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "proj_id"))
    @Where(clause = "is_deleted = false")
    private Set<Project> projects;

    @JsonIgnore
    @Column(name = "is_deleted", nullable = false)
    private Boolean isDeleted = false;

    @Override
    public Long getId()
    {
        return this.id;
    }

    @Override
    public void setId(final Long id)
    {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName()
    {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(final String name)
    {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public Set<Project> getProjects()
    {
        return projects;
    }

    public void setProjects(final Set<Project> projects)
    {
        this.projects = projects;
    }

    public Department getDepartment()
    {
        return department;
    }

    public void setDepartment(final Department department)
    {
        this.department = department;
    }

    public Set<Qualification> getQualifications()
    {
        return qualifications;
    }

    public void setQualifications(final Set<Qualification> qualifications)
    {
        this.qualifications = qualifications;
    }

    public Boolean isDeleted()
    {
        return isDeleted;
    }

    public void setDeleted(final Boolean deleted)
    {
        isDeleted = deleted;
    }

}
```

`Department` class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "DEPARTMENT")
public class Department implements Serializable, Identity<Long>, Deleted
{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @WhereJoinTable(clause = "is_deleted = false")
    @JoinTable(name = "DEPARTMENT_EMPLOYEE", joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "department_id")},
            inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "employee_id")})
    @SQLDelete(sql = "UPDATE DEPARTMENT_EMPLOYEE SET is_deleted = true where department_id = ? and employee_id = ? and is_deleted = false")
    private Set<Employee> departmentMembers;

    @Column(name = "is_deleted", nullable = false)
    private Boolean isDeleted;

    @Override
    public Long getId()
    {
        return this.id;
    }

    @Override
    public void setId(final Long id)
    {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @Override
    public Boolean isDeleted()
    {
        return this.isDeleted;
    }

    @Override
    public void setDeleted(final Boolean isDeleted)
    {
        this.isDeleted = isDeleted;
    }

    public String getName()
    {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(final String name)
    {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public Set<Employee> getDepartmentMembers()
    {
        return departmentMembers;
    }

    public void setDepartmentMembers(final Set<Employee> departmentMembers)
    {
        this.departmentMembers = departmentMembers;
    }
}
```

When call `PUT /employees/{id}`:
[image: PUT Employee]

Calling `PUT /departments/{id}`:
[image]

As you can see in the screenshots of the debugger the `id` field of `Department` is populated while it is null in `Employee`. I'm testing this with Swagger and I am setting the ID in the payload. I don't have any specific Jackson configuration set I just use Spring boot's default but I cannot work out why only in Employee the `id` field is never mapped.

`Employee` body:

```
{
"id":1,
  "name": "New Name"
}
```

`Department` body:

```
{
"id":2,
  "name": "chemistry",
"deleted":false
}
```

Comment: What are the bodies that you are passing to the calls?

Comment: @NiVeR updated with body data.

Comment: Where do interfaces `Deleted` and `Identity` come from?

Comment: they're defined by me. they just declare getters and setters and both entities implement them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was due to a Jackson annotation `@JsonIdentityInfo` on another entity `Project` which is has a relationship with `Employee`:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "PROJECT")
public class Project implements Serializable, Identity<Long>, Deleted
{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinTable(name = "EMP_PROJ", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "proj_id"), inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "emp_id"))
    @JsonIdentityInfo(generator = ObjectIdGenerators.IntSequenceGenerator.class, property = "id")
    @Where(clause = "is_deleted = false")
    private Set<Employee> employees;
```